# Nginx – read value from redis and store it into variable

Tags: nginx, redis, subdomain

Is there any way to read redis value and store it into nginx variable?

I want to use it for multi-domain website, where subdomains will point to different IPs. All the subdomains will be stored in redis like this:

```
"subdomain" => "address_for_proxy_pass"
```

So what I need is to parse subdomain (done), store it into variable (done) and than make redis query (done) and store the result into variable. How to do this easily?

Comment: Can't you just generate nginx config and use it? Or do you want to query redis on each page request?

Comment: Hi, Sergio! I want to query redis only if subdomain is present. And subdomains will be dynamically added so I can't generate config each time new subdomain is created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[set_by_lua](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#set_by_lua) + [ngx.location.capture](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#ngxlocationcapture)?

Comment: Yep! I wrote to @agentzh and he gave me a good advice: http://openresty.org/#DynamicRoutingBasedOnRedis

Answer (score 0):

lua-resty-redis can not be used in `set_by_lua` - https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-redis#limitations

But, `$foobar` can be set directly in lua via `ngx.var.foobar` using `access_by_lua`. Details are available here: http://openresty.org/#DynamicRoutingBasedOnRedis (thanks to the OP and comments).

The variable must be initialized - `set $myvar ''`

```
  # initialize variable
  set $backend '';

  access_by_lua '
  local redis = require "resty.redis"
  local red = redis:new()
  -- these ENV vars must be initialized with `env` keyword
  red:connect(os.getenv("REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_ADDR"), os.getenv("REDIS_PORT_6379_TCP_PORT"))
  local res, err = red:get(ngx.var.appid)
  -- set the variable directly
  ngx.var.backend = res
  ';

  proxy_pass http://$backend;
```